# Where to write custom data access method for EF6 code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository

I am using Entity Framework 6 code first for my data access layer.

I understand that as of version 6, the `DbContext` implements the Unit of Work pattern, and each `DbSet` implements the repository pattern.

With that being the case, where should custom access method be placed in this architecture. Ie. methods that run queries against the entity.

For reference, my data context class looks like:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext() : base("DatabaseContext ")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Account> Account { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Country> Country { get; set; }
    etc...
}
```

And my entities are generally in the form:

```
public class Account
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int AccountId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    etc...
}
```

My guess is these methods would go in the entity class itself, which would allow me to access them in the form `DataContext.Account.GetAccountById` (for example):

```
public class Account
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int AccountId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Account GetAccountById(int accountId)
    {
        // but how do I get the data context?
    }
}
```

The problem with this, of course, is that I can't access the DataContext from inside the Entity.

Can anyone advise?

**EDIT**

I have come up with this method, which allows me access to the DbContext and to mock the call. Can anyone confirm if this is reasonable?

```
public class AccountDbSet<T> : DbSet<T> where T : class
{
    public virtual T GetAccountById(int id)
    {
        return this.Find(id);
    }
}
```

Then the Data Context:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext () : base("DatabaseContext ")
    {
    }

    public virtual AccountDbSet<Account> Account { get; set; }
    etc...
}
```

Comment: I think answers are going to primarily opinion based.  There's no correct answer to this question

Comment: My 2c would be to implement your own repository with DbSet as a member, don't expose it directly to an application. This will help dissuade business logic ending up in the UI layer and force that logic to be implemented within the repository.

Comment: @Mick but isn't DbSet essentially a repository on it's own? Doesn't that just add unnecessary classes on top?

Comment: Unless your application is extremely simple, you're going to need a layer in which to encapsulate the business logic specific to your solution, DbSet offers simple constructs to get and set entities from your database.  Complex queries, validation etc, that has to be done somewhere.

Comment: @Mick, just so you know I did end up going the generic repository route. I just couldn't find another way. That said, it seems like in EF7 that `DbSet` has been made `public abstract` and so my suggestion in the question may work.

Answer (score -2):

I do not know if there is a built-in EntityFramework functionality for doing this, but talking about C# in general, you may create an extension class:

```
public static class EntityFrameworkExtensions 
{
    public static Account GetAccountById(this DbSet<Account> dbSet, int accountId) 
    {
        return dbSet.Find(accountId);
        // or dbSet.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == accountId) for non-primary key columns
    }
}
```

Then, somewhere in your code:

```
int id = DataContext.Account.GetAccountById(5);
```

Comment: This seems like a very unwieldy way of doing it, especially as the number of methods and entities grows.

Comment: @Steve I just have described one approach, which can be suitable or not :) By the way, you can split your extension methods, i.e. `AccountDbContextExtensions` etc.